# How to select rows from pandas based on values of a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and one of the columns (let's say col_1) is a list of string. I'd like to select only rows from the dataframe where the col_1 (which is a list) contains a particular keyword, e.g. 'late'. Here is an example

```
                col_1 col_2
0          [no issue]   fff
1  [late.., no issue]   fff
2           [late...]
```

So I'd like to select rows 2 and 3.

Comment: [prerequisite](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a condition check to each row:

```
df[df.col_1.apply(lambda x: 'no issue' in x)]
```

Comment: it's a bit different from what I need, I need the list to contain an element which has the keyword 'late'!

Comment: Well, change 'no issue' to 'late', what's the problem?

Comment: 'late' is a substring in the elements

Comment: Then you have to say so in the question. It is not clear, and it makes the difference.

Answer (score 0):

does this help?

```
df['New'] = np.where(df['col_1'].str.contains('late'), 'late', np.nan)
print(df)
             col_1 col_2   New
        [no issue]   fff   nan
 [late,..no issue]   fff  late
         [late...]   NaN  late
```